# Angular 4, 5, 6 how to create placeholder while loading like facebook?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

How to create background loading lines like facebook did while loading the content using Angular 2 +[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read what your error message tells you.

I'm pretty sure the [up] input is no longer supported so instead try something like:

```
<div ngbDropdown placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ng build -prod --aot=false
```